# Disabling a Simulink Subsystem

Tags: simulink

I have a question regarding Simulink subsystems. Is there a way to disable an Enabled subsystem based on its own output? I tried doing it the way it is shown in below picture but it just gives an algebraic error. [Simulink Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiViy.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not a good idea. Once a sub-system is disabled, it can't be re-enabled again if you do this. The output of the sub-system is only calculated when the system is enabled. Once it is disabled, the output state will never change.

Comment: Basically, once the condition inside that subsystem goes HIGH, I want that loop to stop and execute some other subsystem. Any ideas on how to make that happen?

Comment: I'd use a separate bit of logic, say a stateflow chart, to determine which sub-systems should be active at which time. When your condition goes high, it can trigger a change of state in the state machine to enable the next sub-system.